# How to set 1.1 API version as default in Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have such settings that set my v1 as default:

```cs
services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
{
    config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
});
```

How can I set 1.1 to `DefaultApiVersion`? There are no string, double or float constructor of `ApiVersion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you misunderstood this setting.

Are you setting like this:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
{
    config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1.1, 0);
    config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
});
```

and it will report an error.

check the source code about `ApiVersion`, It is described like:

```
// Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion class.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   majorVersion:
        //     The major version.
        //
        //   minorVersion:
        //     The minor version.
        public ApiVersion(int majorVersion, int minorVersion)
            : this(null, majorVersion, minorVersion, null)
        {
        }
```

So, you just need to set:

```
//version 1.1
config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });
```

Comment: I have it already. Versioning works well, i just need to replace default one